# How to install .d.ts file from github:DefinitelyTypes using typings

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, tsd

I used tsd which is now deprecated and am trying to use typings. The typings repository is very small, and I can't find any of the d.ts files I need. All the files I need are in GitHub DefinitelyTyped repository, but I can't find a way to install them using typings.

Here is a command I tried:

```
typings install github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/angular-formly/angular-formly.d.ts
```

I receive the error:

```
typings ERR! message Attempted to compile "angular-formly" as a dependency, 
but it contains some ambient module declarations
("AngularFormly", "angular-formly").
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To install angular-formly definitions from DefinitelyTyped, use the following command:

```
typings install angular-formly --ambient
```

It's taken directly from here: [Quick Start](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings#quick-start)

EDIT: Because this is the accepted answer and syntax has changed, as of typings 1.0:

```
typings install dt~angular-formly --global
```

Comment: try it, it does not work - you receive an error message saying "unable to find angular-formly in the registry". If you look at the typings registry, it has only about 30 entries comared with the multiple hundreds in DefinitelyTypes.

Comment: I have tried it before posting. It does work. Moreover if you check the link it explicitly says that by using --ambient flag you will instruct 'typings' to check definately typed  for definitions. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: my bad, you are right (I misspelled ambient to ambiant - the problem being french speaking sometimes!)

Comment: So, what does the `ambient` flag do that makes it work?

Comment: This adds the dependency to the project but apparently you need to instal the dependency manually.... How do you install the dependency manually?

Comment: This adds typescript definitions to the project. Not dependency. If you want to add dependency (whose definitions you had installed with `typings`) - add it to `package.json` -> `dependencies` and then run `npm install` to fetch it.

Answer (score 13):

As of version 1.X of typings the syntax has changed and is now:

```
typings install dt~angular-formly --global
```

update:
As of typescript 2.0 types are installed using npm:
`npm install @types/angular-formly`

Comment: Thank you!  This isn't well-documented across the web.  The typings project documented it well, but of all of the tutorials and SO answers I've read, this is the first I've found that mentions this.  Crucial. More info: https://github.com/typings/typings/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Comment: **Note the tilde**: dt<tilde>angular-formly

Comment: I was motivated to attempt to author something comprehensive related to finding / using typings https://neoheurist.wordpress.com/2016/06/20/definitely-typed/

comments and feedback welcome/requested - I want it to be as useful / authoritative as possible

Answer (score 4):

I use the following:

```
./node_modules/.bin/typings install whatever --save --global --source dt
```

Seems to be the way to do it in v1.3.1.